# SQL Server Reporting Services - Custom security module

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Take the following two scenarios:-

Developer A has created a set of reports:-
Report A shows details of Audi car sales
Report B shows details of Mercedes car sales
Report C shows details of Volvo car sales, and so on for each of 30+ manufacturers.
So we have 30 report files (.rpt).

Developer A has done this so he can assign different security permissions to each AD group of users:-

Group A can only see Audi car sales,
Group B can only see Mercedes car sales,
Group C can only see Volvo car sales, and so on.

Developer B has taken a different approach:-

She has created a single report (one .rpt file) that accepts a 'manufacturer' parameter in order to display the data for any manufacturer.

In both scenarios the reports are loaded from a report 'menu'. In the first scenario a hyperlink for each manufacturer takes you to the relevant report. In the second scenario the same hyperlink supplies the manufacturer name to the single report as a parameter.

The downside with this scenario is the single report file cannot be locked down to a specific set of users. If the report was locked down to Group A, then Group B or C could not view it at all.

Onto the question:-

In order for us to make the second scenario viable we would need a way of checking to see if the current user, or the current users group has access to view the data they are requesting.

I was thinking of using a custom function, something like `CheckAccess(Username,Manufacturer)` that returns a true or false, and depending on the return value either redirect the user to load the report, or to an error page respectively.

Another option would be to set up roles for each manufacturer, then assign the roles to each group of people. Could a custom function then be used to check if 'Bill' has the 'Audi' role ??

Looking for ideas here as to the best approach.

Comment: Is your initial report an ssrs report or something else? Also I'm assuming by the way you asked the question you can't alter the developers reports, buy you can alter the initial one?

Comment: I can alter any report. It's just I'd rather go with the second scenario due to not having to create multiple semi-identical reports.

Comment: That's good I would also prefer the second. My answer below should work well.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you:

1. Create a table with the userid and report parameter in it. This way the security of the user access can be managed.
2. Then use the ssrs `User!UserID` reference as a parameter in your query.

As an added benefit you can create a query to only populate the manufacturers the active user is allowed to see.